# Efficiently grouping sets based on number of similar items

Tags: python, set, grouping

I have a list of sets of the form

```
animals[0] = {'cat', 'cow', 'dog'}
animals[1] = {'cat', 'cow', 'pig'}
animals[2] = {'cat', 'dog', 'fish'}
animals[3] = {'tiger', 'fish', 'pig'}
animals[4] = {'dog', 'fish', 'pig'}
```

How can I group sets that have at least 2 similar items ? To make it simple, I will use a dict whose key is the first element of the overlapping set and do not care if some of the items belonging to that key have lesser than 2 similar items. For example,

```
g['cat'] = [0,1,2]
g['fish'] = [2,3,4]
```

because list 0 and 1 have the overlapping items cat and cow and list 0 and 2 have the overlapping items cat and dog. list 1 and 2 however, only have the overlapping item cat but are still included in the dict. A simple brute force approach would be to iterate through the entire list and check each list with every other list.

```
for i,x in enumerate(animals):
    for j,y in enumerate(animals):

        intersection = x & y
        if(len(intersection)>=2):
            dict[list(intersection)[0]].append(j)
```

But this is very time consuming if I have a very large list I think and so I would like to learn a better way to do this. If anyone has any function to recommend.

Comment: Hi! How big are we talking about? It this is a market-basket problem, I could suggest various approaches based on how big the dataset to handle is.

Comment: Shouldnt `fish` have `[2,3,4]` here?

Comment: This question is questionable. animals[2] = {'cat', 'dog', 'fish'} and animals[4] = {'dog', 'fish', 'pig'} have 2 same item, why not 4 in fish dictionary?

Comment: @RoadRunner and Marcus.Aurelianus yes u are correct :) I forgot about that in my example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution using cosine similarity

### About sparse matrices

If you are talking of a **large dataset**, you should consider using a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). In particular, the technique I am going to describe scales well and can be used with [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)-like frameworks.

Before proceeding, therefore, I'll convert the example you have given into a sparse matrix. By no means the following approach is the fastest one, usually it depends on how you data are generated, for example if you already have a complete set or you are dealing with an online algorithm working on a stream.

#### Notes on unknown full set

If you are dealing with an *unknown* complete set, common issue when dealing with online algorithms, you can try and create an hash function family built to map your keys to *N* and gradually and hash functions until you have an low enough *false positive* rate (keys mapping to the bucket of another key).

#### Converting the sets to a sparse matrix

We will now proceed [*assuming*](https://www.xkcd.com/1339/) that you have an ordered full set called `all_the_animals`, that allows you to map the unordered set to *N*.

```
animals = [{'cat', 'cow', 'dog'},
{'cat', 'cow', 'pig'},
{'cat', 'dog', 'fish'},
{'tiger', 'fish', 'pig'},
{'dog', 'fish', 'pig'}]

all_the_animals = ['cat', 'cow', 'dog', 'pig', 'fish', 'tiger']
```

The actual conversion:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse

def binarise(sets, full_set):
    """Return sparse binary matrix of given sets."""
    return sparse.csr_matrix([[x in s for x in full_set] for s in sets])
```

So to get the sparse matrix you would run:

```
sparse_matrix = binarise(animals, all_the_animals)
```

### Using the cosine similarity

Once you have the sparse matrix, you can proceed using the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) from [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html), it being defined as:

[image: Cosine similarity]

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
similarities = cosine_similarity(sparse_matrix)
```

#### Visualising cosine similarity

The obtain similarity matrix looks like, using [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
seaborn.heatmap(s, annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.show()
```

[image: Cosine similarities]

### Thresholding

Now you can choose a threshold of similarity. For example, in your question, you are asking for the *2/3* of the elements to be in common:

```
threshold = 2/3
```

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) you can execute:

```
import numpy as np
similar = np.where(similarities >= threshold)
```

*Obtaining:*

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]))
```

### Extracting the similar groups

Now that we have the set of similar_animals we can run:

```
similar_sets = [(i, similar[1][similar[0]==i]) for i in np.unique(similar[0]))]
```

*The result looks like:*

```
[(0, array([0, 1, 2])),
 (1, array([0, 1])),
 (2, array([0, 2, 4])),
 (3, array([3, 4])),
 (4, array([2, 3, 4]))]
```

To visualise the results you can use the ordered set to get the animals name:

```
similar_animal_sets = [(all_the_animals[i], similar_set) for i, similar_set in similar_sets]
```

which outputs:

```
[('cat', array([0, 1, 2])),
 ('cow', array([0, 1])),
 ('dog', array([0, 2, 4])),
 ('pig', array([3, 4])),
 ('fish', array([2, 3, 4]))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution ! I also forgot about the cosine similarity which, for my case is very helpful as all my lists are of fixed length.